# How to mock viewmodel which is not a parameter of the action?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, moq, viewmodel

Below is the piece of the code of my action :-

```
   public ActionResult Edit(int id)
   {        
       ProductViewModel viewmodel = GetProduct(id);

       if (viewmodel != null)
       {
               ....................
       }
    }
```

In above code the if condition is based on the viewmodel.Which is returning from the GetProduct() method.Where GetProduct() method is the private method of the controller.

And i want to mock the **ProductViewModel** in my unit test method with MOQ.Can anyone suggest me what is the best way to do that ?

Comment: A view model is typically just a data container.  So, you should be mocking the `GetProduct()` method and have it return just some static data (or a null since you need to test that)

Comment: `ViewModels` are typically data structures shaped for a view... what is the value in mocking it?

Comment: @Tommy,GetProduct() is the private method of controller and i am not mocking the private methods.And to test the stuffs inside viewmodel condition i want to mock the viewmodel.

Comment: I would make the argument that your application structure is wrong.  `GetProduct` is a business logic method that should not be private and should be in a business logic layer / class. That is why you are struggling to accomplish what you want to do with your testing.  The way you are structured now, there is no entry point to inject any values into that controller.  In order to do that, you will need to look into Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control type programming methods.

Comment: @Tommy,may be you are right but it is the old structure of my application and currently i can't modify it.But is there any way,where i can mock the viewmodel and can test the further part of my action ?

Comment: Not with the way this code is structured.  You have to be able to either override a function to return an expected set of values or 'inject' the values into the function.  There are no entry points in your current code to allow you to accomplish this that I can see.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally your viewModel should only have public properties that your view will be bound to. So there should not be a scenario where you would need to mock the viewModel class.
If it is possible to, mock the GetProduct method to return an instance of ProductViewModel where the public properties have already been set. That way your viewModel will return exactly the values you want it to return for your test case.

Answer (score 0):

Usually using the MVVM pattern will look like :

```
public class MainViewModel : MyViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;

    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        // ...
    }
    //..
}
```

And you'll have a locator that looks like:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        }

        // Here you'll register your view models
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }  
    //..
}
```

So, mocking this is fairly easy, just use the DI to pass in whatever you want to pass, and hook your methods either to static data (usually done to have nice output in design mode), or dummy methods that will return whatever it is you need.

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to test indirectly the GetProduct method. Based on the name you are getting info from some kind of storage and you can mock that storage and return an object which is mapped by GetProduct in the ViewModel you want. You shouldn't mock method of the same class you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is very strongly coupled with the business logic, in this case the GetProduct method. I would suggest to restructure your code to have an interface for your "Product" specific business logic. The product controller should depend on an abstraction i.e. the interface and not anything that is concrete.

Use any dependency injection framework like sring.net, MS unity etc to inject concrete implementations (dependencies) into your controller.

Now use MOQ to mock the business logic so that controller can be tested in isolation.

Lastly, this is just another wonderful example demonstrating how if it becomes difficult to unit test a particular code component, it more than often points towards a design flaw than a unit testing/mocking framework incapability.